# How to determine tomorrow's date in J2ME for use in a DateField?

Tags: java, datetime, java-me

I basically want to be able to show tomorrows date

I have this which shows today date

```
private Date date = new Date();
```

i tried this but this gave me jan 1 1970

```
private Date date = new Date(+1);
```

please help

Answer (score 7):

The integer (actually long) parameter for the Date constructor is for specifying the milliseconds of offset from January 1st, 1970, GMT.

You need to use a Calendar instead

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, the `Date.setBlah` and `Date.getBlah` methods are deprecated, [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) should be used instead. (Not sure if that's available in J2ME though.)

```
private Date date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: class Date has been deprecated for years now, I don't think there's the risk of it disappearing over night... but you're right, Calendar is better written and should usually be used.

Comment: To be totally fair, java.util.Date is not deprecated, just the methods for treating a Date as a collection of fields.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here, use <strike>an implementation of</strike> class Calendar like thus:

```
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
long tomorrow = myCalendar.getTimeInMillis() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
myCalendar.setTimeInMillis(tomorrow);
```

And do whatever you want with that...

Hope this helps,

Yuval =8-)

Comment: Why make your own Calendar implementation?  Why not just use Calendar.getInstance() ?

Comment: Why indeed? must have been the late hour that made me forget about getInstance. noted and edited.