# How to determine tomorrow's date in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am trying to determine tomorrow's date in J2ME and I have already read the following topic 
[How to determine tomorrow's date in J2ME for use in a DateField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757583/how-to-determine-tomorrows-date-in-j2me-for-use-in-a-datefield)
but the problem is I could not able to find the setDate() or setTimeInMillis() method of Date or Calendar class and they do not exist!

[image]

Comment: this works for me  tomorrow1=24 * 60 * 60 * 1000+ d.getTime();       
          d.setTime(tomorrow1);

Answer (score 3):

**This example sets tomorrow's date**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

`Date today = cal.getTime();`

```
day.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Comment: thanks for reply but cal.clone() method does not exist! It says can not find symbol method clode(), I don't know what's going wrong

Comment: i have imported java.util.* ,my device configuration is cldc 1.0 and device profile midp 2.0

Comment: -1 there is no `clone` method in [Java ME MIDP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html)